# Como obter notificações do Firebase recebidas em background?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notification

Implementei o serviço de notificação no meu app, funcionando, inclusive recebe notificação em background, porem eu queria salvar a mensagem da notificação, pesquisei um pouco e criei um serviço ( código abaixo ) funciona, porem só quando o app esta aberto ( em primeiro plano ), em background não funciona.

```
public class FirebaseNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i("PVL", "Mensagem Recebida");
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
            Log.i("PVL", "Mensagem recebida: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        } else {
            Log.i("PVL", "Mensagem recebida: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Você quer salvar a mensagem da notificação onde? No celular?

Comment: Você pode passar dados além na notificação pelo FCM, então em princípio, não tem porque capturar a notificação em si, só passar a mensagem como um dado da notificação e ler no app o dado recebido. Dê uma olhada: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=pt-br

Comment: @acklay a principio quero salvar numa lista, pra posteriomente exibir num listview, fazer tipo um historico de notificações recebidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O fato de nao estar recebendo a mensagem quando o aplicativo está em background é por que o objeto do `push` está sendo enviado como `Notification`. O correto para que recebe em background é com nome de `Data`.

Por exemplo:

```
{
"data": {
    "title": "Push",
    "text": "Nova mensagem",
},
"priority": "Normal",
"to": "/topics/general"
}
```

Assim, em classe service que monta a notification, tu fará o seguinte para capturar o texto da mensagem:

```
 if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        String mensagem = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");    
    }
```

Comment: Estou enviando pelo console do firebase, como enviar como data?

Comment: Consegui, usando o ARC

Comment: Mas uma duvida .. eu consigo implementar essa solicitação post que o ARC faz em um site por exemplo né ?